# Revisiting how to extract times from web page

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I am doing some work on Udemy for my job. I need to extract the times of each lecture so I can put them into my boss for tracking. I have read up on BeautifulSoup. I have gotten down to the class where the time is:

```
<div class="ci-details-container clearfix">
            <span class="ci-details">
                <i ng-class="::getCurrentLectureIcon()" class="icon-play-sign"></i>
                <span>02:29</span>
                <!-- ngIf: ::!elementData.content_summary -->
            </span>
```

Here is how I got there:

```
timeList=soup.findAll("span",{"class":"ci-details"})
```

I am now trying this to try to regex out the times:

```
newTimes=timeList.findAll("span",{"\d\d\:\d\d"})
```

which results in this error:

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    newTimes=timeList.find("span",{"\d\d\:\d\d"})
    AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find'
```

(Should I be using this Regex syntax instead? `[0-9][0-9]\:[0-9][0-9]`)

In my mind, I have taken a list, and made it a smaller list. Am I right or wrong?

I would think my smaller list would have a findAll, findall or even find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findAll` is an attribute of Beautiful Soup's `Tag` class. It is not an attribute of the `list` builtin.

So we need to search through the contents of a list of ci_details and see which of the  `<span class="ci-details">` nodes contain a `<span>` whose content matches a time string - `"^\d\d:\d\d$"` .

This regex uses ^ and $ to specify that a string matches without any leading or trailing characters.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, __version__
import re
import sys

print ("beautiful soup version: ", __version__)
print ("python version: ",  sys.version)
print

m = re.compile("^\d\d:\d\d$")

div = """
<div class="ci-details-container clearfix">
    <span class="ci-details">
        <i ng-class="::getCurrentLectureIcon()" class="icon-play-sign"></i>
        <span>02:29</span>
        <!-- ngIf: ::!elementData.content_summary -->
    </span>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(div)

ci_details = soup.findAll("span",{"class":"ci-details"})
print (ci_details)


timeList = []
for detail in ci_details:
    for span in detail.findAll("span"):
        if m.match(span.text):
            timeList.append(span.text)


print (timeList)
```

I get the following output:

```
beautiful soup version:  4.2.1
python version:  3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
[GCC 4.8.4]
[<span class="ci-details">
<i class="icon-play-sign" ng-class="::getCurrentLectureIcon()"></i>
<span>02:29</span>
<!-- ngIf: ::!elementData.content_summary -->
</span>]
['02:29']
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the pointers. Yet the timeList is not printing out. I am seeing the ci_details just fine.

Comment: Does that actual snippet of code above give you content in your timeList? 
What version of python are you running?
Does changing the regex to `m = re.compile("^\d\d:\d\d$")` give you the results that you need?

Comment: The snippet above does not give me the contents of timeList. Only ci_details. And I used that regex.

Comment: Can you also try the regex seperately and confirm that you haven't inadvertantly got a character wrong (as you did in your original post)? 
`>>> import re; m = re.compile("^\d\d:\d\d$") ; print m.match('00:29')`

Comment: I have modified my code to include some version info. Can you try it again & post the output that you are getting?

Comment: My apologies Chris! I am using Python 3.5. I took your code, put it in idle and ran it. It keeps throwing an error around the

Comment: My apologies Chris! I am using Python 3.5.I had to add () around the print statements as I was getting an error. I commented the first print and this is what I got: beautiful soup version:  4.4.1
python version:  3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:27:37) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
[[<span>02:29</span>]] so if you can point me to docs on how to get the time out of the tags, I will be all set. Thanks for your help so far!! Much appreciated!

Comment: I've updated example to use pyrthon3. Also in bs4 tag.text gives you the contents of <tag>...</tag> .

Comment: Thanks for the updated code! I guess I will need to RTFM more going forward. And the next dumb question: How do I mark this answered so as to give you the credit?

Comment: You click on the Gray Tick next to my answer & it turns to a Green Tick.

Comment: Done and thanks again! Now I need to work on how to take a full webpage, parse it and use this code in it. :) Look for that in a few days hehe